# Effect of increasing mass on wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For a wave function in an infinite potential well, does changing the mass have an effect on the wave function?

I know that for a well of width L

$$ \psi (x) = \sqrt {\frac 2 L}sin(\frac{n\pi x} L)  $$

And from this equation it doesn't seem like there is any term that could depend on n. However, the frequency of the wave can also be represented as

$$ \frac {\sqrt {2mE}} h  $$

In which case there's a clear dependence on mass and I'm not sure how to reconcile those two forms.

Answer (score 2):

Since $E_n\sim 1/m$ the mass dependence cancels out.

Answer (score 1):

The wavefunction is actually

$$\psi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin{kx}$$

Now, since the length of the 1D well is $L$, hence the wavefunction must always terminate to zero at $x=L$ to maintain continuity with the environment outside the box. Hence we get $$\sin kL=0\quad \Rightarrow kL=n\pi$$

But, also the total energy of the wave is Kinetic, since there exists no potential field inside the box and hence

$$E=KE=\frac{p^2}{2m}=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}$$

Thus the Energy of the individual eigenwave $\psi_n(x)$ goes down with increasing values of $m$, but it does not change the probability distribution function at all.